# Assembly - what should be the output

Tags: assembly, mov

I am an absolute beginer when it comes to assembly. I try to figure out what should be the output of the following:

```
Jan dd 255,256
Feb dw 16, 17, 18, 19
Mar db 8, 9, 10, 11

Sub edi, Mar - Feb
mov ebx, Jan[edi]
add bl, Mar
```

So the `Sub edi, Mar - Feb` will subtract first elements from `Mar` and `Feb` arrays giving value of `-8` at `edi`... But then what will be moved to `Jan[edi]` ?? And what will be added to `Mar`?

Could you give me an answer to that exercise WITH explanation. And please forgive me lack of basic assembly knowledge.

Comment: `So the Sub edi, Mar - Feb will subtract first elements from Mar and Feb arrays giving value of -8 at edi` - no `sub edi, Mar-Feb` will subtract the _difference_ between the _addresses_ of `Mar` and `Feb` from what was previously in `edi`.

Comment: `Sub edi, Mar - Feb` will take the address of Feb and subtract it from the address March which will equal the number of bytes in the Feb array(which appears to be 8), and then subtract that  from the value already in _EDI_. Seem that they are simply subtracting 8 from _EDI_

Comment: If you were using NASM syntax (instead of MASM), it would be a lot less confusing.  You could tell that `sub edi, mar - feb` was `sub r32, imm8` because of the lack of `[]`, and that `add bl, [Mar]` was using a memory operand because it does have `[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Sub edi, Mar - Feb` will subtract first elements from `Mar` and `Feb` arrays

It cannot do that. The assembler is not allowed to compute it at assemble time (the stuff in memory is variable, so the result, well, varies), and there is no instruction that can "double-subtract". What it actually does is

1. as assemble time, compute the difference between the *address* `Mar` (which is an address, it is not a bunch of numbers, just the place where they start) and the address `Feb`. There are 4 words in between, size 8 in total, so the assembler will emit the machine code for `sub edi, 8`.
2. at run time, 8 will be subtracted from `edi`.

What's in `edi` though? Well who knows. But now it's 8 less. `mov ebx, Jan[edi]` which incidentally means `mov ebx, [edi + Jan]`, so hopefully `edi` is something sensible, 0 or 4 would make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks @harold for simple explanation! I cannot say that I do understand everything here but I will try with different basic excercises to understand more!

Comment: Thanks @harold for simple explanation! I am bit closer now to understand how assembly works but I think that I have loads to learn!